# Add FROM and TO columns in mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql table Cluster:

```
Date       user   Cluster 
01/01/21    1      A
01/01/21    2      B
01/01/21    3      C 
02/01/21    1      A
02/01/21    2      A
02/01/21    3      B
```

i want to analyse the migration of users to some clusters per date , the output desired is :

```
Date        user  From  To 
01/01/21     1     A    A
01/01/21     2     B    B
01/01/21     3     C    C
02/01/21     1     A    A
02/01/21     2     B    A
02/01/21     3     C    B
```

i tried, but i dont know how to get the  cluster of previous date (To column )

```
SELECT date  , user, cluster as from , (
select Cluster   where date  =  date -1 )
FROM Cluster 
group by date , cluster
```

Comment: Is date really in the form published?

Comment: Are the two dates fixed? Is it always two dates? Is it always two entries per user?

Comment: 'dont pay attention to date' - got to have some way of finding previous record...and what version of mysql are you on?

Comment: i modify the question , its per day

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5 , thank you

Comment: It's usually a bad idea to work with old, unsupported versions of a software. With MySQL it makes a big difference whether to work with MySQL 8 or an older version, because of important features that have been added (namely CTEs and analytic/window functions).

Answer (score 1):

You want to show all users' clusters on a day along with their cluster of the previous day. In standard SQL and MySQL 8 this would simply be:

```
select
  date, 
  user,
  lag(cluster) over (partition by user order by date) as "from",
  cluster as "to"
from cluster
order by date, user;
```

In old MySQL versions this becomes much more complicated usually. If it's all about adjacent dates, however, we can simply join:

```
select curr.date, user, prev.cluster as "from", curr.cluster as "to"
from cluster curr
join cluster prev on prev.user = curr.user
                 and prev.date = curr.date - interval 1 day
order by curr.date, curr.user;
```

Your original query seems to try to do something similar, but you got a little confused with the syntax :-)

If the days are not adjacent, you'll have to number your user rows ordered by date. And as versions prior to MySQL 8 don't support CTEs (`WITH` clauses), you'l have to do this multiple times.

You can also simply show the chain of clusters by the way:

```
select
  user,
  group_concat(cluster order by date separator ' -> ') as clusters
from cluster
order by user;
```